# How to know if message is continuation of conversation?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

This might be a stupid question, but I haven't come across any mention of it in the docs.

How do I know when a message is a continuation of a previous interaction? For example, with BotFather, you send /setdescription and BotFather tells you to send details. You send details and BotFather knows the details are a description for the specified bot.

How does it know about the bot I previously specified?

I want to avoid fully-qualified commands (for lack of a better term) like:

```
/command [parameter] [parameter]
```

and turn them into:

```
[command]
<reaction>
[parameter]
<reaction>
[parameter]
```

Any tips?

EDIT: for right now, I'm simply setting 'status' flags on users every time they finish a step in a multi-step operation. I check that tag after receiving every message to determine if a user is in the middle of an operation. It's rather tedious. I wonder if there's a better way / something built in to the API.

Answer (score 0):

with your message_id you can do this. I guess message_id is identity number and primary key for every chat.